Куда задавать вопросы по теории?
Я задал на stack overflow вопрос, который относится к машинному обучению и немного чуток к статистике, но он был теоретический, и я так понял, меня за это подняли на штыки, т.к. должен быть код или типа того для таких тем - куда такие теоретические вопросы задавать, чтобы их увидели и ответили? (нашёл, что "stack overflow не для мнений/советов" - а как на темы-то ответы находить ;( а здесь вообще как будто никто не сидит, и явно не по таким темам)

У тебя единственный вопрос на сайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1437772/178988, который уж никак не соответствует этому описанию, и ни одного удалённого. О чём вообще речь?

@Qwertiy https://stackoverflow.com/q/79028217/3240681

@αλεχολυτ , да, он, я просто думал, что эта тема не относится к конкретному вопросу, поэтому и не прикрепил его

Русскоязычный и англоязычный SO модерируются разными людьми и правила несколько разные для публикаций. Поэтому странно обсуждать на руСОмете вопросы, опубликованные на enSO.

Здесь такой вопрос тоже  удалят (к сожалению). Наверное надо поискать  в гугле и попробовать разные компьютерные форумы, может где и повезет с его "населением" (в случае успеха киньте сюда ссылочку)

Возможно, просто стоило задать вопрос в другом сообществе, например datascience - Q&A for Data science professionals, Machine Learning specialists, and those interested in learning more about the field

В целом, [tag:теория]
